# I solved slow internet issue but i think i did something wrong?

Tags: networking, drivers

so, i had slow internet for 2 days, i tried everything i could find until i found by casuality some git driver, so i decided to try, i have a usb dongle using driver rl8188eu, with this driver i had 100kb/s max download speed, and i installed [this one][1], which is rl8188eus, yet in the lshw -c networks shows 8188eu, which theoretically is blacklisted with `echo 'blacklist r8188eu'|sudo tee -a '/etc/modprobe.d/realtek.conf'`, the .conf only have that line that i added, nothing more, that looks weird too

```
 *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 15
       serial: 30:9c:23:99:ba:d3
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.19.0-35-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:19 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:df104000-df104fff memory:df100000-df103fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: a
       bus info: usb@1:12
       logical name: wlx18d6c70b2c17
       serial: 18:d6:c7:0b:2c:17
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=8188eu driverversion=5.19.0-35-generic ip=192.168.0.192 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

For the installation i just did `git clone` and then `sudo make` and `sudo make install`, the thing is, first time i did it it wasnt nothing like this, first time the make actually made something yet the make install i think looks the same, but when it worked i got hyped and made a sudo apt upgrade because i had fast internet so i said why not (i guess i updated something that i shouldnt?), now it works but this seems broken, i feel like i did something wrong, but it works, at least for now. So if you guys see something weird or could give me some guidance i would appreciate, is my first time with ubuntu and ive been for 2 days trying to have good internet speed, now i have it but feels wrong lol, thanks!

```
mati@mati-MS-7B48:~/Desktop/asdsasd/rtl8188eus$ sudo make
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.19.0-35-generic/build M=/home/mati/Desktop/asdsasd/rtl8188eus  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-35-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
  You are using:           gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-35-generic'
mati@mati-MS-7B48:~/Desktop/asdsasd/rtl8188eus$ sudo make install
install -p -m 644 8188eu.ko  /lib/modules/5.19.0-35-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
/sbin/depmod -a 5.19.0-35-generic
```

Edit: I realized that now the driver in lshw iss only "8188eu" i think before it was "r8188eu", so maybe isnt that bad?
[1]: https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8188eus

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong at all. The driver that you git cloned and installed is named `8188eu`. The driver that comes by default in recent Ubuntu versions is called `r8188eu`. They are different and have different names.

You built and installed `8188eu` and blacklisted `r8188eu` so that it wouldn't also load and conflict.

Please note that whenever Update Manager installs a later kernel version, after the requested reboot, you must recompile the driver:

```
cd ~/Desktop/asdsasd/rtl8188eus
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8188eu
```

Please retain these instructions for that time.